# How to capture the remote [ rsh/rcp ] login events and information using syslog.conf

Tags: linux, syslog, syslogd

I am exploring ways to capture the remote login events in my Linux server [ Oracle Linux 5x ].
Many users are connecting to the server using rcp and rsh protocols , I wish to capture the events [ such as- server from where they are logging, unix id, file details for rcp ]

In my syslog.conf I am capturing the following details.
local7.* /var/log/ftplogs
authpriv.* /var/log/sftplog

Am I missing any facilities.

Comment: The question(s) you have to ask yourself: are those events showing up in any of my systems current logs?  If so, by which means of syslog did they get there?

Comment: I am able to get the ssh/ftp/scp events in my syslog logfiles. The issue is only with rcp and rsh

Comment: One wild idea is to rename and replace the rcp and rsh commands by scripts that will do the logging and then call the real command.

Answer (score 2):

you need to start `rshd` with `-L` switch on `server_args` parameter within `xinetd.conf`:

```
service shell {
                disable        = no
                socket_type    = stream 
                wait           = no 
                user           = root
                log_on_success += USERID
                log_on_failure += USERID
                server         = /usr/sbin/in.rshd 
                server_args    = -L
              }
```

Comment: I already have this information in my xinetd.conf

Comment: I have a logrotate on the log file, after the rotate few information like rsh are not being captured in the log. Looks like after each rotate I need to restart the syslog service.

Comment: Thanks for the details marcel - I am just curious what does the "log_on_success += USERID" will do in your xinetd.conf

Comment: So maybe your question's regarding logrotate not keeping to log after rotate? I know logrotate has some issues when SIGUSR1 not being sent to the PID, but I don't know for sure. Might want to google some.

Comment: By adding the following in the logrotate file  [ postrotate ; /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> ] , The syslog started capturing the auth.info correctly which enables the rcp and rsh- Thanks